# pointer to structures in C/C++

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, struct

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct node NODE;

struct node{
    int value;
    NODE *next;
};



void addNode(NODE *prev)
{
    NODE* next=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    int value;
    cin>>value;
    next->value=value;
    while(prev->next!=NULL)
    {
        prev=prev->next;
    }
    prev->next=next;
    next->next=NULL;
}


int main()
{
    int ch;
    NODE* curr=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    NODE* trav;//=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    trav=curr;
    curr->value=10;
    curr->next=NULL;
    while(true)
    {
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                addNode(trav);
                //trav=next;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                trav=curr;
                while(trav!=NULL)
                {

                    cout<<trav->value<<endl;
                    trav=trav->next;
                }
                break;
            }
            case -1:{break;}

        }
        if(ch==-1)break;
    }

    free(curr);
    free(trav);
}
```

I was trying to implement the linked list data structure. The above code works well, however, I do not understand one thing. I have not created even a single instance of the struct node, all of them are simply pointers, and I allocate memory to these pointers on the heap. Where are the nodes actually stored since according to me, pointers store only the address and nothing else. As in when I use next->value, where is that value stored?
Usually I use pointers in this manner.

```
int a; 
int *p;
p=&a;
```

Now, here I know at some point in memory there is a stored and p is pointing to that location. However in these node structures, there is no real instance, simply memory allocated on the heap.

How does it work?

Comment: Huh? You create instances of nodes on all of the `malloc` lines. The storage of the nodes is in that memory that you malloc'd.

Comment: Why tagged C when it is C++? Why using `malloc` when using C++

Comment: in c++ you can avoid malloc using new and free with delete.

Comment: It's been a long time since I wrote some C but I'm pretty sure that freeing curr and trav is not enough to free every node of a linked list.

Comment: @EdHeal this is neither C nor C++, it is a hybrid language which takes the worst of both language (i.e., uses structs and malloc/free as object system but streams for managing I/O because the syntax looks clever). I have seen this stuff in high school books from '90.

Comment: @pqnet - `cin` suggests C++. `malloc` C. You cannot use `Cin` in C but you can use `malloc` in C++. Therefore it is C++. BTW What is wrong with streams - they offer type safety

Comment: @pqnet: Actually it's C++: It is a program that is required to be accepted by a standard-conforming C++ compiler. It is certainly not *good* C++.

Comment: @celtschk Is it bad because of malloc and free and structs? I will keep it in mind that I should use new and delete. Regarding structs, I know how to code linked lists using classes and objects as I learnt data structures in Java while in school. I wanted to learn how it works at a lower level of abstraction :) Thanks for everyone's views. I feel much more enlightened now.

Comment: Using `malloc`/`free` is one of its problems, yes. Those functions are there for C compatibility and should not be used in C++-only code. Another problem is that you use them without including the appropriate header (it is no requirement that `iostream` indirectly includes that; I didn't notice that problem when I claimed that the code is required to compile, indeed due to that problem it isn't). Also, `typedef struct node NODE` doesn't really make sense in C++; since a type that was defined as `struct node` can be referred to as `node`, the typedef just adds a superfluous name without need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by your second code example, it's understandable that normally you would **point** to **existing** variables with your pointers.

Well, now you **create** them yourself (using malloc).
They're created in a different section of the memory called the **heap**, and they **are** real instances. just like they would be real on the stack. malloc just 'finds' a space for you to store them.

A linked list would look a something like this on the heap:

[image]

Note that the linked list consists only of: head(8) -> 3(10) -> -7(2) -> 13(14) -> 5(0) .
Every other part of the heap is not used by this list.

Found the image source [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~snyder/cs112/Homeworks/HW04/HW05.pointers.png).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is clear to me now. I figured that malloc simply returns a pointer to the memory location, does not lead to the creation of any instance.

Comment: @chintanshah I don't see how this (confusing) picture clarifies this better than stated in my answer (especially in how it shows what should be done in order to fix any problems), but as you wish :P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Thanks for your answer. My doubt was that when I use pointers to structures, there is really no instance for the pointer to point to. This answer made me understand that malloc really creates an instance, but on the heap. I figure malloc returns the starting address of the structure?

Comment: @chintanshah `malloc()` returns the starting address to a piece of memory on the heap, that at least reserves enough space to store a valid instance of `NODE`, but in contrast to `new()` no initialization for that instance is done.

Comment: @arnon-zilca Putting pictures looks sexy, but doesn't really explain what's the real problem/misconception though :P ...

Comment: I usually agree, It's just that the question wasn't all that clear about what **exactly** was misunderstood so I fired in all directions. :) btw, first time I actually used a picture. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> and I allocate memory to these pointers on the heap.
>
> *"As in when I use next->value, where is that value stored?"*

As you mentioned, the `value` member is also stored on the heap. The `sizeof(NODE)` statement will ensure the necessary memory is reserved.

---

> *"there is no real instance, simply memory allocated on the heap."*

In terms of c++ this statement is almost right, at least these *instances* aren't correctly initialized. Though the reserved memory is treated as there were usual c++ instances stored there.
To achieve standard c++ `struct`/`class` initialization, you may change your `addNode()` function as follows

```
void addNode(NODE *prev) {
    NODE* next = new NODE(); // Use the new() operator for c++ struct/class
              // ^^^^^^^^^^^ // initialization
    // ...
}
```

`malloc()` only provides allocation of memory on the heap, while the c++ `new()` operator will ensure that any appropriate constructors (also those created by default by the compiler) will be called, after the memory allocation took place. With c++, there are standard initializations for struct/class members provided by the compiler, unless explicit constructors and member initializations are defined.

**NOTE:**
If you use the `new()` operator, you ***must*** use `delete` instead of `free()` to release the allocated memory. Similarly as `new()` guarantees constructors to be called, `delete` guarantees that destructor functions are called correctly.

---

The lines

```
free(curr);
free(trav);
```

won't do what you expect either way. You should have some kind of `LinkedList` struct/class, or at least a fixed `NODE* head` reference, that keeps track of the allocated memory/instances and deletes these when going out of scope.

You'll need some kind of memory management, as provided by the [`std::list<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) class. May be you could just use it, instead of brewing your own.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that while `malloc` just allocates memory, but doesn't construct an object there, `struct node` is a so-called POD type ("POD" stands for "Plain Old Data") which means, besides other properties, that its minimal "construction" consists of *doing nothing.*

Now of course it does not hurt if you omit the step of doing nothing. That is, an object of POD type "magically" comes into being if you assign some memory location a value of that type. And indeed, the standard explicitly allows this for POD types.

On the question of how to identify a POD type: The rule of thumb is that the POD types are those you could also use in C.